# PostreSQL- How to convert float containing a number of seconds to MM:SS.sss

Tags: postgresql, time, formatting

I have a float8 that contains a number of seconds ie 65.455. I was trying to format a column in a view so that it would read as 1:05.455.

Using postgres command like this:
TO_CHAR((user_data.totaltime || ' second')::interval, 'MI:SS')

I can format it as 1:05  but i loose the precision i need.

Anyone know of a way to achieve what i need ? It doesn't look like interval allows the formatting of milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `justify_interval`:

```
SELECT justify_interval(
          CAST(65.455::text || ' seconds' AS interval)
       );
```

Comment: That throws an error: 

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function justify_interval(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 356
  ERROR: function justify_interval(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 356
  ERROR: function justify_interval(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 356

Comment: It was missing a type cast; fixed.

Comment: Accept answer as it is almost the best way of doing it ;-) I did find that the following worked just as well in my view definition:

(timetest.runtime)::text::interval AS runtime_t1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather brute force you may do this, using the base string functions:

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(65.455 / 60)::text || ':' || LPAD(FLOOR(65.455 % 60)::text, 2, '0') ||
        TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM (65.455 % 1)::text);
```

This outputs:

```
1:05.455
```

### Demo

Comment: A bit brutal, but works perfectly .... and as my data will only ever have a few hundred rows will work just fine ;-)